# boost::trim and std::bind2nd

Tags: c++

I am trying to use `boost::trim` on a vector of strings. I understand that [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221871/625914) works elegantly, however I cannot understand why

```
std::for_each(df.colnames.begin(), df.colnames.end(),
    std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(boost::trim<std::string>), std::locale()));
```

doesn't work. I get error:

```
error: ‘typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::pointer_to_binary_function<std::basic_string<char>&, const std::locale&, void>; typename _Operation::result_type = void; typename _Operation::first_argument_type = std::basic_string<char>&]’ cannot be overloaded
```

Why `std::bind2nd` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this I think:

1. `ptr_fun` requires that its argument return a value.  See:
   http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ptr_fun.html
2. `bind2nd` doesn't work with reference arguments.  See: [Using std::bind2nd with references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464439/using-stdbind2nd-with-references)

Moral of the story:
`boost::bind` hides a shocking amount of complexity.

If you really want to make it work and don't care about passing strings/locales by value you can wrap trim as follows:

```
int trim2(std::string s, const std::locale loc)
{
  boost::trim<std::string>(s, loc);
  return 0;
}
```

And then do:

```
std::for_each(df.colnames.begin(), df.colnames.end(),
    std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(trim2), std::locale()));
```

P.S: (1) may be library-dependent.  I just tried with g++ and it didn't have a problem with a void return.